# Limiting the number of times a unique value can be entered into a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am learning to use SQL Server 2012 and I am wondering what is the best way to limit a columm to only allow each value to be entered a maximum number of times?

E.g. a column `Color` that will only allow `Blue` to be recorded up to a maximum number of three times?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you would want something like a stored procedure to do the insert.  You'd query the table for a count of matching colors.  If less than your max, insert, else return an error.

Comment: or (and im cringing as a type this) a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a constraint to *constrain* your data, and leave triggers for the (hopefully) rare instances where you are forced to implement business logic in the db (when a new color is inserted, do xyz).

Here is a constraint based way using a function bound to a check:

```
--setup
create table dbo.Color (ColorId int primary key, ColorName varchar(10), Cap int);
go
create table dbo.Detail (DetailId int identity(1,1), ColorId int references dbo.Color(ColorId));
go

--create color blue with max row cap of 3
insert into dbo.Color
    values(1, 'blue', 3);
go

--create a func to evaluate the max row cap 
create function dbo.IsColorCapped(@ColorId int)
returns bit
as
begin
    return  (   select  case when count(*) > max(c.Cap) then 1 else 0 end
                from    dbo.Color c 
                join    dbo.Detail d on 
                        c.ColorId = d.ColorId
                where   c.ColorId = @ColorId
            )
end;
go

-- use the func in table constraint
alter table dbo.Detail add constraint ck_ColorCap check (dbo.IsColorCapped(ColorId)=0);
go

-- Test...

-- insert 3 blue rows
insert into dbo.Detail (ColorId)
    values(1),(1),(1);

-- insert 4th blue row - FAIL
insert into dbo.Detail (ColorId)
    values(1)
/*
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_ColorCap". The conflict occurred in database "yak", table "dbo.Detail", column 'ColorId'.
The statement has been terminated.
*/

-- incease the color cap
update dbo.Color
set Cap = 4
where ColorId = 1;

-- insert 4th blue row again
insert into dbo.Detail (ColorId)
    values(1);
```

Comment: Does the value in the Identity Column increase if a insert command fails due to the check constraint?

Comment: Yes, an identity value is never transactional. Any DML operation that is rolled back will consume an identity value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [stored-procedure](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/) to do your insert. There you can check how many records already exist with `Color = 'Blue'`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertColor @Color nvarchar(30), @ColorCount int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @ColorCount = count(*) 
FROM dbo.ColorTable
WHERE Color = @Color

IF @ColorCount <= 3 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ColorTable(COLOR) VALUES(@Color);
END

COMMIT
GO
```

You could execute it in this way:

```
DECLARE @ColorCount int
EXEC sp_InsertColor @Color = 'Blue', @ColorCount = @ColorCount OUTPUT
SELECT @ColorCount
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a transaction in there?

Answer (score 0):

The store procedure method mentioned in this thread will work but it's only good if it's used by everything doing an insert. A better way is to enforce it in a trigger using similar logic. A trigger will guarentee the enforcement of the rule. Check the count of the inserted color in the trigger and if it equals the max count, bail out. Don't forget to also check updates, not just inserts.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[ColorTableTrigger] ON [dbo].[ColorTable] 
FOR  Insert 
AS
DECLARE @colorCount int
begin
SELECT @ColorCount = count(*) 
FROM dbo.ColorTable
WHERE Color = inserted.color


If @colorCount = 3  (
        rollback tran
    RAISERROR <some user defined error>
    )
end
end
```